# Spring's value annotation does not work in constructor argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Service**

```
@Service
class Foo{
   Foo(@Value("${my.property}")int delay){
    ...
   }
}
```

**Consumer**

```
class Bar {
    @Autowire
    Foo foo;
}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="foo.*" />
<context:spring-configured />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo/internal.properties"/>
```

`internal.properties` does contain `my.property=5000`. But it seems like spring does not even care about the `@Value` annotation. If I run the application, spring complains about that there is no default constructor found.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [foo.Foo]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException...
```

I even tried to configure the parameter in beans.xml using the `constructor-arg` tag. This method produces the same error.

Why is the value injection not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Service
class Foo{
  @Autowired
  Foo(@Value("${my.property}")int delay){
    ...
   }
}
```

You forget to add `@Autowired` in your constructor.

From **Spring 4.3** we no longer need to specify the `@Autowired` annotation if the target bean only define  `one constructor`

Comment: Great information about not needing `@Autowired` for single constructor class.

Answer (score -2):

I think your problem is that, **you are missing constructor** (check your exception). For Bean is important to create default (no args) constructor. More about this you can read [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/01/why-default-or-no-argument-constructor-java-class.html). This is good article.